# Advertisement to appear above and below the main layout in ListView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, adview

I want to display a picture advertisement at the bottom of the display area.  I've tried using **bottom** but it didn't work.  Can you help me?

```
MainActivity.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        ></include>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

   <ListView
       android:id="@+id/ilcelerListview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Picture link : [For Example](http://i.hizliresim.com/RoBaBn.png)

Comment: Corrected grammar and wording.

Answer (score 0):

I can give your two tip to do that.

You can use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout at MainActivity.

For that, you can easy to add a view which you want to add to bottom.

Or

```
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT);
```

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

//you can use params to set in the bottom or other positions

//view is yours

```
    rootView.addView(view, params);
```